# I thought about asking my girlfriend to marry me there

Tags: word-choice, sentence-construction, sentence-meaning

how can I correctly say:

> I thought about asking my girlfriend to marry me there.

This sentence looks like that I thought about asking my girlfriend to marry me in someplace when I want to actually say that I thought about proposing my girlfriend there.

Answer (score 2):

Some sentences do have a duality of meaning, it doesn't mean they are wrong. For example "*I went to work on a train*" could mean either you *travelled* to work on a train or you were employed on it.

If you want it to be clearer you should use different wording:

> I thought about proposing (marriage) to my girlfriend there.
>
> I thought about asking my girlfriend if we could get married there.

Comment: _I went to work on a train_ has a potential third meaning, too. A mechanic might start working on, say, the underside of a train, without ever setting foot inside the carriage.

Comment: The British novelist Fay Weldon is supposed to have invented a well known advertising slogan "Go to work on an egg".